# Fantasy children's story where they suspect someone is a vampire

Tags: identification-request

I'm 38 and read this probably between 1993-1997.... when I was between 8-12 years old. I don't think it was a new book at that time.

It was about a young boy and girl who auditioned for a local play where they thought the lead actor was Dracula and tried to solve the mystery of whether he was or wasn't a vampire.

The girl got the part because she had a better stage scream. I remember the young girl saying "it's my peasant girl costume" but that is about it. I believe they only suspected him, and he turned out to be a normal person.

Comment: And here I was thinking the Bailey School kids... although that one is *Vampires Don't Wear Polka Dots*.

Answer (score 9):

You're describing [*The Case of the Visiting Vampire*](https://archive.org/details/caseofvisitingva00robe) by Drew Stevenson.

> Where did you come from?” I asked Verna. “And why are you dressed like
> that?”
>
> “This is my peasant-girl costume. I told you tonight was a dress
> rehearsal.

Overall your description is very good. A foreign actor is presumed to be a vampire and seen flying around at night as a bat. In the final analysis it turns out that he isn't anything of the sort.